# Вывод переменной в подключённом файле с помощью include

Tags: php, переменные

Добрый день. У меня такая проблема - не могу понять причину.
Например имеется **index.php**, в первой строчке объявляю переменную

```
$test
```

потом с помощью

```
include('test.php');
```

подключаю файл **test.php** и в нём хочу вывести переменную **$test** выводит ошибку

```
Notice: Undefined variable:
```

Answer (score 3):

Почему Вы используете include как функцию? Насколько я знаю, корректное включение выглядит так:

```
include 'test.php';
```

При этом переменная может быть использована в обоих файлах.
Пример рабочего кода:

**test.php**

```
<?php
$test = "TEST";
?>
```

**main.php**

```
<?php
include 'test.php';
echo $test;
?>
```

[Документация `include` на русском](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.include.php)

[*Не забудьте принять ответ, если он Вам помог.*](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/faq/#heading10)

Comment: это не функция. Это просто группировка. А то что выглядит как функция - ну ой. =)
Я у принта и эхи всегда скобки пишу. Потому что привычнее.

Comment: да я тоже попробовал в отдельном файле сработало значит у меня ошибка в другом месте, большое спасибо

Comment: @knes мего солидарен!

Answer (score 1):

index.php:

```
<?php
$test = 'dfg';
include 'test.php';
```

test.php:

```
<?php

print('test');
print($test);
```

вывод:

```
testdfg
```

Вот наоборот не прокатит из-за области видимости.

Comment: ? или я чтото не понял или имеется ввиду, что подклюить файл и вывести переменную из него?

Comment: написано именно так как я изложил.